# reading pcap capture file crashes

Tags: c++, libpcap

trying to read one-by-one packets from capture file:

```
pcap_t *  structure = pcap_open_offline(file, errbuf)
```

and then

```
pcap_pkthdr** hdr=new (pcap_pkthdr*);
const u_char** data=NULL;
while(pcap_next_ex(structure, hdr, data) == 1)
{.....}
```

thus, the pcap_next_ex crashes with core

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
[New process 7928]
(gdb) bt
0x0804a038 in pcap_fakecallback ()
0x08057ac4 in pcap_offline_read ()
0x0804ae19 in pcap_next_ex ()
0x08049b3d in main () at ..
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: capture file is present, the "structure" pointer is not NULL

Comment: I think you need `pcap_pkthdr* hdr; const u_char* data; while(pcap_next_ex(structure, &hdr, &data) == 1) { ... }` but I can't test so don't want to post as answer.

Comment: @tinman **you are right**, it returns from pcap_next_ex(). Thanks a lot! I don't know how to mark your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation at [this WinPcap page](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcapfunc.html#g439439c2eae61161dc1efb1e03a81133):

> pcap_next_ex fills the pkt_header and pkt_data parameters (see pcap_handler()) with the pointers to the header and to the data of the next captured packet.

This means that you only need a single pointer (not a pointer to a pointer) for the second and third parameters, but you pass the address of those pointers. The function then sets the pointer values to point to the additional information it returns. So your code would be something like this:

```
pcap_pkthdr* hdr;
const u_char* data;
while(pcap_next_ex(structure, &hdr, &data) == 1)
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in storage for the pcap_pkthdr, so pcap_next_ex can store data there.

Moreover, pcap_next_ex will set the data pointer to point to the packet data,
which the pcap library keeps internally(so the place your data pointer points to
will only be valid until you call pcap_next_ex again.)

You need to do this:

```
pcap_pkthdr hdr;
const u_char* data=NULL;
while(pcap_next_ex(structure, &hdr, &data) == 1)
```